# Openshift OKD 4.5 on VMware

Tags: openshift, vmware, okd

I am getting the connection time out when running the command in bootstrap.

Any configuration suggestions on networking part if I am missing

It’s says kubernetes api calling time out

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously very hard to debug without having access to your environment. Some tips to debug the OKD installation:

- Before starting the installation, make sure your environment meets all the [prerequisites](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-vsphere-installer-provisioned-customizations.html#prerequisites). Often, the problem lies with a faulty DNS / DHCP / networking setup. Potentially deploy a separate VM into the network to check if everything works as expected.
- The bootstrap node and the Master Nodes are deployed with the SSH key you specify, so in vCenter, get the IP of the machines that are already deployed and use SSH to connect to them. Once on the machine, use `sudo crictl ps` and `sudo crictl logs <container-id>` to review the logs for the running containers, focussing on the components:

  - kube-apiserver
  - etcd
  - machine-controller
- In your case, the API is not coming up, so reviewing the logs of the above components will likely show the root cause.